# Convert Integer to Date in R

Tags: r

in my data set the values for date is like this '10.01.2012' and I want to convert it to Date "10/01/2012", but it's not working. I've looked at many examples here but they haven't worked for me. Can someone help me please!

Comment: use `dmy( stringToConvert )` from `lubridate` package

Comment: That's NOT an integer. It's digits separated by periods. Use `as.Date` with a format string. Read `?as.Date`. There are examples to be reviewed. When converted it will be printed as `2010/01/10` unless you use `format.Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue here is that we actually do NOT know what 10.01.2012 is: is it Jan 10, or Oct 1:

```
R> as.Date("10.01.2012", "%d.%m.%Y") 
[1] "2012-01-10"      
R> as.Date("10.01.2012", "%m.%d.%Y")    
[1] "2012-10-01"   
R>
```

But you do, presumably, so pick either `%d.%m.%Y` or `%m.%d.%Y` as needed.  But there is a reason we all like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats ...

Comment: Presumably, functions in the `anydate` package would examine several instances to improve the guess at m-d vs d-m.

Comment: Yes, but because of the non-determinism I ... more or less folded and just added %m/%d variants (with different separators).  The recommendation for ISO 8601 still stands.  (Oh, and the package is called [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) but contains functions `anytime`, `anydate` and UTC variants thereof.)

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I'd tried before, but in a wrong way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please feel free to accept (click on "tick" mark) and/or upvote (clikc on up-ytriangle) the answer if it helped your question.

Answer (score 0):

My old frien use `gsub()`

```
x = "10.01.2012"
gsub('\\.', '/', x)
[1] "10/01/2012"
```

Comment: Never use regexp on Dates when date parsers could be used.